# What is the difference between a pointer to a buffer and a pointer to a file?

Tags: c, file, buffer, stdio

In Chapter 22 of "*C Programming: A Modern Approach*", the basics of the `<stdio.h>`header are explained.

One detail that has me a little confused is the difference between a *pointer to a buffer* and a *pointer to a file* (denoted as `FILE *`).

Consider the following (through which the confusion is derived):

`fopen` is prototyped as: `FILE *fopen(const char * restrict filename, const char * restrict mode)`.

`fflush` is prototyped as `int fflush (FILE *stream)`. `fflush` is described as a function the flushes a file's buffer.

`setvbuf` is prototyped as `int setvbuf (FILE * restrict stream, char * restrict buf, int mode, size_t size)`. When the author describes this function, he refers to the second parameter (`buf`) as the *address of the buffer*...which presumably is the same idea as *pointer to buffer*.

Firstly, from what I understand (especially given the name choice of the first parameter in `fflush` and `setvbuf`), a **stream** is semantically equivalent to a **pointer to a file**. Importantly, therefore, a stream **IS NOT** the file itself. A stream is the **location** of the file, at least as is represented through virtual memory (please correct if this is off base).

Secondly, when one opens a file, this amounts to creating a corresponding buffer (that is also represented in virtual memory).

At first, because of `fflush`'s prototype, I was under the impression that the pointer to a file was *in practice* the pointer to a buffer; this is clearly wrong given the prototype of `setvbuf` (which has distinct parameters for the pointer to a file and the address of the buffer). So what exactly is the pointer to file **pointing to**?

Further, how does one acquire the address associated with a given file's buffer (the author has not shown a function yet the returns the address of a buffer associated with the file that was opened).

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Cheers~

Comment: `fflush is described as a function the flushes a file's buffer` That's not describing the parameter to `fflush`. It is describing what `fflush` does. So "buffer" in that description does not directly equate to the `stream` parameter. That is, it flushes the buffer associated with that file. A file pointer is simply a pointer to an implementation dependent data structure. It does not correspond directly to virtual memory. It's an opaque structure as far as client code is concerned and is used by the implementation to track the state of that particular stream.

Comment: @kaylum when I use fopen, is a buffer automatically created?

Comment: Yes a default buffer is created. As you may already know, you can  change the buffer with the `setvbuf` call. That is, if you don't want to use the default buffer created by `fopen` (or you want to make the stream unbuffered) then call `setvbuf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms “stream” and “file” are a bit muddled in C. A file is something outside the program, and it may be a physical device, a file on disk, or some other thing provided by the operating system.

A stream is, roughly, an interface to a file. It is largely constructed in the C environment by using various data structures to remember information about the file it is connected to, to hold data being written to or read from the file, and so on.

For historic reasons, a stream is managed through a data structure type called `FILE`. A `FILE *` is actually a pointer to a stream (or, more technically, a pointer to the data used to control a stream). The data in a `FILE` includes a file position indicator, a pointer to its associated internal buffer (not anything you should use), and information about errors that have occurred or whether the end of the file has been reached. It would be better if the name were `STREAM` instead of `FILE`, but we are stuck with `FILE` due to history.

A buffer is often an array of `char` or `unsigned char` used to hold data being moved between various things, although there can be buffers of other types. The `buf` argument to `setvbuf` is used to provide a buffer to be used with the stream. This is not a commonly used routine. Passing an array to `setvbuf` **gives** the array to the C library to use for that stream. The program should stop using the array for any other purpose until it closes that stream. This is different from an array you use to read or write characters using the other functions like `getchar` or `fputc`.

Comment: @EricPostpischill thank you for the thoughtful response...addressed a good deal of my confusion. I assume the array is of type character because we want the buffer to store information one byte at a time?

Comment: @S.Cramer: Character types, particularly `unsigned char`, are used in C to handle “raw data,” that is, sequences of bits without regarding to their meanings. All objects in C—arrays, structures of mixed types, pointers, everything—can be treated as sequences of bytes. So arrays of `unsigned char` can be used to manage those bytes in transit from one place to another.