# How is "file position" implemented in a stream (FILE)?

Tags: c, file, buffer, stdio

In Chapter 22 of the book "*C Programming: A Modern Approach*, the author devotes a brief section to the concept of **file position**. The following description is provided:

> Every stream has an associated ***file position***. When a file is opened, the file position is set at the beginning of the file. (If the file is opened in "append" mode, however, the initial file position may be at the beginning or end of the file, depending on the implementation.) Then, when a read or write operation is performed, the file position advances automatically, allowing us to move through the file in a sequential manner.

After this paragraph, the author dives into several `<stdio.h>` functions (e.g. `fseek`, `ftell`, etc), which are related to this notion of "file position".

I made a post recently ([What is the difference between a pointer to a buffer and a pointer to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64094346/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pointer-to-a-buffer-and-a-pointer-to-a-file)), and the provided answer / feedback gave me a decent beginner's understanding of what a stream, `FILE`, and `FILE *` actually are. Also revealed to me in this post was the fact that buffers can be automatically ("*by default*" created when `fopen` is invoked).

So my question is really a request: could someone provide me, in some greater detail, **what exactly file position is**? Is it a pointer to the buffer related to `fopen`? If it's not a pointer *to a buffer*, does it somehow bare some sort of correspondence TO a pointer to a buffer? Presumably file position is stored inside `FILE`. etc etc.

Any insight is greatly appreciated! Cheers~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file position is a number associated with the underlying file 'handle'.  That handle would be a file descriptor on POSIX-like systems (strictly the 'open file description' as opposed to 'open file descriptor', but you can forget that distinction for the time being — see POISX [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) for more information).  It would probably be a '`HANDLE`' on Windows (but I reserve the right to be wrong on that).  It doesn't matter too much as the `FILE *` abstraction isolates you, the programmer, from the low-level details.

The file position specifies an offset in bytes from the start of the file where activity (reading or writing) will occur.  The position is changed by reading or writing data, or by seeking to a new position.  The kernel (operating system) keeps track of the position, moving it when necessary.  The structure pointed at by the file stream (`FILE *`) may also track the position in its data.  That's because it has to ensure that changes to the buffer are properly reflected in the file, and changes in the file are properly reflected in the buffer.  The buffer contains data associated with some range of positions in the file.  That range changes as data is read or written, or as the program seeks on the file.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response! So, just for clarification then, there IS a correspondence between the data that has been read into the buffer and the file position stored in the FILE object that FILE * points to. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes — there is a correspondence between the data that was read into the buffer (or written to the buffer) and the file position.